# that and who(or which) usage for a noun phrase

Tags: grammar

I think I read from somewhere(I think it was 'element of style') that below one is more appropriate. but I'm not sure that I remember correctly.

1. All the guitarists, that I admire, are bald.
2. All the guitarists, who I admire, are bald.

Am I right? Is there a more natural way to put this?

Comment: I wonder why your sentences so seldom begin with capital letters. And why you include the second sentence in each example? Is it relevant? "All the guitarists I admire are bald" is more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both sentences there should be no comma after guitarists unless you mean to say that you admire all guitarists. I think you mean to point out the coincidence that of all the guitarists in the world those whom you admire (that is, not all of them) are bald, so the comma is omitted to show that you are talking about 'the guitarists I admire'.

In the second sentence some would prefer 'whom' to 'who'. Some would prefer 'whom' to 'that' because the former clearly refers to people and 'that' does not. You will nevertheless find 'that' used in such contexts. You can avoid relative pronouns altogether as @OldBrixtonian's comment does.